# BigQuery - FULL OUTER JOIN with USING causes casting error

Tags: google-bigquery

I work in BigQuery and I have a task to do. I have to compare values of two tables and search for differences. I have decided to convert values to string, unpivot these tables and join them with unique ID and name of the column. I have decided to use `FULL OUTER JOIN`, because I can't be certain that every single ID is present in both tables. I've tried to join tables with USING clause, but it gives me casting error, when I try to use standard CAST in WHERE clause.

```
Error running query
Invalid date: 'test'
```

This code reproduces the issue:

```
WITH RawData AS (
    SELECT 'text' AS type, 'test' AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'number' AS type, '123' AS value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'date' AS type, '2020-12-12' AS value
),
Joined AS (
    SELECT 
        IFNULL(a.type, b.type) AS type,
        -- type,
        a.value AS a_value,
        b.value AS b_value
    FROM RawData AS a
    FULL OUTER JOIN RawData AS b ON a.type = b.type -- NO ISSUE
    -- FULL OUTER JOIN RawData AS b USING (type) -- CASTING ERROR
    -- LEFT JOIN RawData AS b USING (type) -- NO ISSUE
    -- RIGHT JOIN RawData AS b USING (type) -- NO ISSUE
    -- JOIN RawData AS b USING (type) -- NO ISSUE

),
Filtered AS (
    SELECt * FROM Joined WHERE type = 'date'
)
SELECT *, CAST(a_value AS DATE), CAST(b_value AS DATE)
FROM Filtered
WHERE 1=1
    AND CAST(a_value AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE('2020-12-01') AND DATE('2020-12-31')
    AND CAST(b_value AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE('2020-12-01') AND DATE('2020-12-31')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way BQ is compiling your CTEs, the `CAST(a_value as DATE)` in your final `WHERE` clause is trying to be evaluated as if it were right after your self join and is causing a conversion/casting error before the other filters are applied.

I find it helpful to do as much casting as early as possible:

```
WITH 
    RawData AS (...),
    Joined AS (
        SELECT 
            IFNULL(a.type, b.type) AS type,
            SAFE_CAST(a.value AS DATE) AS a_date, -- Handle casting ASAP
            SAFE_CAST(b.value AS DATE) AS b_date
        FROM RawData AS a
        FULL OUTER JOIN RawData AS b USING (type) 
    ),
    Filtered AS (
        SELECT * FROM Joined WHERE type = 'date'
    )
SELECT * FROM Filtered
WHERE a_date BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
  AND b_date BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31'
```

Even better would be to filter your table before you do a join so it is joining fewer rows!

```
WITH 
    RawData AS (...),
    Filtered AS (
        SELECT 
            *, SAFE_CAST(value AS DATE) AS date_value -- Handle casting ASAP
        FROM RawData 
        WHERE type = 'date'   -- Reduce Size Early On!
          AND SAFE_CAST(value as DATE) BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-31' -- Only do it 1 time here since it is the same range!
    ),
    Joined AS (
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(a.type, b.type) AS type,
            a.date_value AS a_date,
            b.date_value AS b_date
        FROM Filtered AS a
        FULL OUTER JOIN Filtered AS b USING (type) 
    )
SELECT * FROM Joined
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but why my code works with ON and not with USING?

Comment: For the reason I mentioned at the top of my answer.  Can you double-check your submitted code?  I get the same error if I choose any of the 5 joins.